# Not able to make video from numPyy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, opencv

If i have a variable whose type i an numpy array. How can i convert it to a video. The is a huge numpy array so i would reommend that to go down , you use the scrollbar on the right. I got the numpy array from capturing my own video and then got its array

When I am running the code, a window is opening and imeediately closing and an error statement is printed:

cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:/projects/opencv-python/opencv/modules/highgui/src/precomp.hpp:137: error: (-215:Assertion failed) src_depth != CV_16F && src_depth != CV_32S in function 'convertToShow'

'cv2.error:' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

operable program or batch file.

As the code was too long because of the long numpy array this is the link to the google drive file:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1v1ZQT7W3XbzcmT5oaPTAQ3hYJ94TJUCH/view?usp=sharing

Here is the structure of the code:

```
import cv2 , time , numpy
frame = numpy.asarray(the long list which was too large so i could not pate it here. see it with the link above)

while True:

    # check, frame = video.read()
    # print(check)
    # print(type(frame))
    # grey = cv2.cvtColor(frame , cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    #time.sleep(3)
    cv2.imshow("capturing" , frame)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key==ord('q'):
       break
```

PLease help me with this..

Answer (score 0):

The issue can be fixed by converting the image to uint8 format. The following code worked for me on your image.

```
    import cv2 , time , numpy
    frame = numpy.asarray(the long list which was too large so i could not pate it here. see it with the link above)

         while True:

                # check, frame = video.read()
                # print(check)
                # print(type(frame))
                # grey = cv2.cvtColor(frame , cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
                time.sleep(3)
                frame = frame.astype(numpy.uint8)
                cv2.imshow("capturing" , frame)
                cv2.waitKey(0)
                key = cv2.waitKey(1)
                if key==ord('q'):
                   break
```

Comment: But that just shows a photo. what can I do to get a video out of it? Please see the other question of mine which has a better explanation regarding it.